# How to implement EJB 3.0, JPA, Hibernate and Struts 2 in one application?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, struts2, ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0

Good day,

I have to use EJB 3.0, JPA, Hibernate and Struts 2 in one application, but I have no idea how to do it! 
Are any other MVC frameworks better integrated with EJB than Struts 2?

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Why do you have to use that set of technologies? If there is an existing application it should give you a clue (since I'd assume it is working) or if there are other programmers they should be able to help you.  I think more struts2 programmers use Spring over EJB... I think more programmers in general use Spring over EJB.

Comment: Which of the technologies have you integrated so far? Which are you having trouble with. I can tell you that it is possible to use each of these technologies in a single web application, but as it stands your question is really broad.

Answer (score 4):

Well, what you're asking for is not all that difficult, although I recommend approaching it in steps or phases if you're unfamiliar with the aspects of the frameworks. I typically start by getting my MVC web application working fist.

**Step 1:**
In your case I would get your Struts web application working. Develop a simple hello-world application, get a feel for how the struts action classes interact with your views(jsp) pages and how to manipulate the value stack.

**Step 2:**
Next I would explore the JPA architecture, you specified Hibernate as the JPA framework, so build a basic java application and play around with the database interaction. Build a couple data access classes to query data and get a feel for how to interact with your database.

**Step 3:**
Next try combining your struts actions with the JPA classes you built in step 2. You should be able to query data using the data access classes you built in your JPA practice project. Once you understand how to combine these two, start looking into EJB options for Struts.

Here is an article similar to your requirements: 
http://www.tzavellas.com/techblog/2007/07/03/using-dependency-injection-in-struts2-for-stateless-ejbs-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

JSF is better integrated within Java EE 5+.
Especially when you use Facelets (iirc official default in JavaEE 6), this will work well. RHQ (http://rhq-project.org/ ) used to make heavy use of JPA + EJB3 + JSF in versions up to 3 (RHQ 4 is switching to GWT), so that you will still find many examples in it.
   Also I think there are many JSF+JPA+EJB3 examples out there.

You may want to have a look at CDI ("Seam") too, as this makes integration of the components easier.

Comment: How specifically does JSF integrate better with EJB3?

Comment: Probably by the fact that it is included in the JEE umbrella standard and thus compliant container are already set up accordingly, while Struts is something you need to completely set up and configure yourself.

Comment: Having used EJB 3.0 with Struts2, I can't imagine that JSF is better integrated, but I've never used JSF.

Comment: It takes me about 30 seconds to a minute to set up a new struts2 project with maven... I know for a fact that I can't just start writing JSF code without telling my IDE, something about the project (like it being a web project). Then another minute to add my DI framework of choice.  Generally "well integrated" is a misnomer, these days we want separation of concern that is why DI and AOP is becoming so prevalent (We don't want 'integration' in the general meaning rather the complete opposite, we want frameworks that are independent of eachother).

Comment: As far as the 'completely configure yourself'... Many struts2 users are using conventions (they all should be I'd say, but that is another matter). There hardly anything to configure. The framework maps urls to your package structure, and then executes the right object and populates the right jsp with those values.  Naturally you need to know a little about how to names things but it is quite easy. The "convention over configuration" mantra started by other frameworks is a good one. EJB is at the service layer, as such should be quite independent of web application concerns.

Comment: I inject Spring services into my Struts2 actions with @ejb and there is no business logic in them, just processing for the view technology (JSP in my case). So if I was to change out Spring for EJB there would not be any changes to the struts2 objects.